# SetWindowsHookEx - Dll Injection misses out on the first few calls

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am trying to use SetWindowsHookEx to capture calls to a API in java.dll.

So I created another dll, and injected into all other processes using setwindowsHookEx

g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, JLoadSetFunc, g_hHookDll, 0)

The problem is following:

While trying to capture calls from a process, I notice that my dll get attached to that process after a couple of calls to the hooked function has already been executed.

So the problem is my hooking mechanism misses the first few calls of the hooked API.

Please suggest or comment on this problem to guide me.
I am stuck terribly with this one.

Comment: The dll is loaded as soon as the main thread of the process receives a message through the window procedure. If that takes place after the function is called you want to monitor, you'll miss some calls. Try http://newgre.net/ninjectlib

Comment: Is there any solution for the above problem? Have you used ninjectlib before? Is it stable?

Comment: Is your DllMain called after the few functions that you are referring to ? otherwise you should be able to hook/re write IATs in the Dll main

Does your process to inject the dll start after the target process?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest the following:

1. Register your hook using SetWindowsHookEx()
2. SendMessage() to the remote process with a special message that only your hook understands
3. Repeat this until your hook replies
4. Call the code you want your hook to interact with

In short, wait for the hook to finish installing before you try using it.

Answer (score 1):

@MSalters

A little correction: not into every process - it is loaded only to processes that import/use user32.dll, and not all processes use it (however I agree that most processes do use it).

See [Working with the AppInit_DLLs registry value](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/197571) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There's an awfully dirty hack to load DLLs into every process using a registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\AppInit_DLLs`

Comment: IIRC this has been disabled in Vista